# Anomalous root word frequency in Scripture

Tags: product-recommendation, words, tanach, internet, search

Is there a program available online that can detect statistically significant higher incidence of a specific root (שרש), and/or of a specific sequence of letters, in a specific portion of *Tanach*. For example, one might input the root שוב, or, alternatively, the sequence of letters שב,  to determine if their incidence in *Parshath Miketz* is abnormally high.

(Related question: [Where is there a good online source to check how often a word appears in Tanach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/where-is-there-a-good-online-source-to-check-how-often-a-word-appears-in-tanach)
though I'm looking for something that would provide, as well, some statistical information - if only to show that a higher incidence in a specific portion is somewhat anomalous.)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I have seen to what you are describing is Alhatorah's concordance graph. It graphs frequency of roots across **different books** in Tanach (although not parashiot, as far as I can tell). Also, their concordance is the best one that I am aware of online - try it out with different roots, forms, and play around with the settings to learn more.

Sample:
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Graph/7725

Comment: Dicta also offers a very nice search function that does the same thing ([example here](https://search.dicta.org.il/result?text=%D7%A9%D7%91&page=1)), although I don't think they display the results graphically.

Answer (score 2):

Accordance, which is available for purchase [online](https://www.accordancebible.com/) (there's also a free version that gives you some text access, but I don't recall how much), allows these kinds of searches. For example, in the picture below, I looked for all verbs in Miketz and sorted them by hits by root (you can see the frequency in percentage, or make a pie chart, ...). You can then see from the list which roots appear much more often than others. You can also search for a select set of roots and compare their frequencies, and you can also see more involved analytics.

[image: Accordance program screen capture. Left: Miketz with the verbs highlighted. Right: a frequency count of verbs by root.]