# I am looking for a pasuk that has to do with doors or entranceways

Tags: torah-study

I am a photographer and am in the midst of a project where I took many different, beautiful, unique doors from the old city of Yerushalayim and Tzfas. I plan to make a collage of all the doors, and want to include an inspirational pasuk (not too long of a pasuk though), something about doors or entranceways...

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: Devorie Zutler, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for the question! Consider checking out our short [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour), which explains a bit how this site works, as well as [this help center article](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) about the best way to ask questions on the site.

Comment: There are many pesukim involving doors and entranceways. To find examples, you can try searching a database or concordance (see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9425) and [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119153)) for relevant words such as דלת, שער, מזוזה, or פתח. If there is something more specific you are looking for, you may [update](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/132897/edit) your question to include more detail.

Comment: ChatGPT: 

Psalm 24:7: "Lift up your heads, O gates! And be lifted up, O ancient doors, that the King of glory may come in."

Isaiah 45:2: "I will break in pieces the doors of bronze"

Proverbs 8:34: "Blessed is the one who listens to me, watching daily at my gates, waiting beside my doors."

Ezekiel 44:2: "This gate shall be shut... for the Lord, the God of Israel, has entered by it."

Song of Solomon 5:5 "My hands dripped with myrrh..., on the handles of the bolt."

Job 38:17: "Have the gates of death been revealed to you, or have you seen the gates of deep darkness?"

Comment: Psalms 118:19-20 is probably your best bet

Answer (score 3):

There are many verses involving doors and entranceways. Some examples were provided in the comments above. Here is another example that might fit what you are looking for:

The eight and ninth chapters of Mishlei present an allegory where wisdom is personified as exhorting people to heed it. In that context, the personification of wisdom discusses its doors and entranceways in [Mishlei 8:34](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2808.htm#34):

> אַשְׁרֵי אָדָם שֹׁמֵעַ לִי לִשְׁקֹד עַל דַּלְתֹתַי יוֹם יוֹם לִשְׁמֹר מְזוּזֹת פְּתָחָי

Translation:

> Fortunate is the man who listens to me, to eagerly watch<sup>1</sup> over my **doors** every day, to guard the doorposts of my **entranceways**.

D'varim Rabba ([7:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%96_%D7%91)) interprets this as a reference to the doorways of synagogues and study halls:

> מהו "לִשְׁקֹד עַל דַּלְתֹתַי" אמר הקב"ה אם הלכת להתפלל בתוך בית הכנסת אל תעמוד על הפתח החיצון להתפלל שם אלא הוי מתכוין להכנס דלת לפנים מדלת לשקוד על דלתי אין כתיב אלא "עַל דַּלְתֹתַי" ב' דלתות ולמה כן שהקב"ה מונה פסיעתך ונותן לך שכר

> ומהו "לִשְׁמֹר מְזוּזֹת פְּתָחָי" א"ר יהודה בר סימא וכי יש מזוזה בבתי כנסיות אלא מה המזוזה הזו אינה זזה מהפתח כך לא תהא זז מבתי כנסיות ומבתי מדרשות

Rashi (Mishlei 8:34) echoes this interpretation, and indicates that this verse is an exhortation for a person to seek to be the first one to arrive to the study hall and the last one to leave:

> על דלתותיי – להכנס ראשון לבית המדרש ולצאת אחרון

Radak (ad loc.) proposes that this is a reference to the figurative doorways of Torah study and mitzva observance:

> אשרי אדם שומע לי – מאושר יהיה האדם שישמע אלי וישקוד על דלתותי תמיד כלומר ללמוד ולשמור ולעשות

The Ralbag (ad loc.) states that a person should eagerly and diligently delve into Torah study and look to expound whichever entranceway of Torah exposition reveals itself to him:

> אשרי אדם שומע לי – להמשך אל מה שאורהו אל השגתי וזה בשישקוד על דלתותי תמיד לשמור מזוזות פתחי עם שיתבאר לו באי זה פתח יכנס בדרש דרוש

The Malbim (ad loc.) interprets this verse as meaning that wisdom is figuratively hidden away behind closed doors and only reveals itself periodically at the entranceway. People should eagerly await and take advantage of such opportunities to find wisdom revealed:

> אשרי אדם שומע לי לשקוד על דלתותי יום יום – מצייר את החכמה שהיא יושבת סגורה בהיכלה כבודה בת מלך פנימה לא תתראה לאיש והדלתות סגורות והמבקש אותה צריך לשקוד בשקידה רבה על דלתות הסגורות לשמור מזוזות פתחי – לשמור את העת שיפתח הפתח שאז ימצא החכמה בעת תתראה דרך הפתח

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>The word שקד carries a dual meaning and indicates both watching as well as eager alacrity and diligence (Rashi, ad loc., "לשקד – לשמר. על דלתותיי – להכנס ראשון לבית המדרש ולצאת אחרון"; Metzudos, ad loc., "לשקוד – ענין מהירות כמו שוקד (ירמיהו א׳:י״ב). למהר לבוא אל דלתותי בכל יום ולשבת בקבע במזוזות פתחי כדרך השומר היושב ומשמר בקבע").</sub>