# Where to find references of words in the Tanach and other ancient texts?

Tags: words, tanach

I am interested in understanding the usage of some words in their biblical context, as the centuries have changed the meaning of some words. Given a word, for instance עולם, how might I find all usages (including conjugations) of the word in the Tanach and in other ancient texts?

Other words of interest would be חשמל, רע, אהבה, לנחש all of which have different meanings and connotations today than they did at the time the books of the Tanach were written.

Comment: Any concordance will do it. Here's one:
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance_Module_1Heb.html

Comment: @Kazibácsi Thank you, I had never heard the term "Concordance". Without the term it was impossible to find such a thing. You might as well post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it, it will likely help others unfamiliar with the word.

Comment: I had a feeling that your question has already been asked, and [indeed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9425/15256). In such cases, we close the question as duplicate, but your question will help others to find the answers there.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Thank you, the linked question and answers do contain the needed information, but not in any way that I would recognize given a goal of identifying _where_ a word is used, as opposed to discovering _how many times_ it is used. Perhaps to some people it would be obvious that a question asking "how often" would also answer "where", but for me the linked question looks like `sort | uniq -c` where I need `grep`.